# Qubes OS. Upgrades? Rolling release?

Tags: qubes

I currently run Arch Linux and I am considering moving to Qubes OS. I am spoiled by Arch's rolling release upgrade feature. I don't think Qubes OS supports rolling release.

After I install Qubes OS, are future upgrades to new releases of the OS easy? Or do they involve a full rebuild of my system?

Answer (score 1):

Qubes OS installs packages mostly "normally" (download via a net VM, then install them).
It's done for Dom0 and the template VMs individually.
Even a distribution update (like moving to the next fedora) can be done that way, but it takes significantly longer.